# Billing with Authorize.net ARB Billing on specific dates instead of an interval

Tags: magento, intervals, authorize.net, authorize.net-arb

I have a subscription which happens on four specific dates on during the year according to a custom cycle . I want to get people to subscribe but get billed together on the same day every 2 months. If I set it to 2 month interval everyone gets charged separately according to the day they subscribe . Can a fixed payment date be  set  with ARB Recurring billing ?

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is charge the user using the AIM API and pro rate their first payment up to the first scheduled payment date. Then the ARB subscription will take over. That's all there is to it.